# Swift doesn't pickup NSMutableArray type annotation from framework

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

I've created a framework in objC and I'm creating an extension for a class in a Swift file in the main project.
I've annotated the class (in the framework) as follows:

```
@interface GerberStepAndRepeat : GerberElement <GerberBlock>
@property (nonatomic,strong,nonnull) NSMutableArray<GerberLevel *> *levels;
@end
```

In Swift I access the `levels` property as follows:

```
extension GerberStepAndRepeat {
    func flatten() {
        for level in self.levels {
        }
    }
}
```

The `levels` property is then typed as `NSMutableArray` and the `level` variable is typed as `Element`.

Why doesn't it show the types that I've specified in the framework? Are there any settings I need to tweak to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Interacting with Objective-C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID173) (emphasis added):

> Objective-C declarations of `NSArray`, `NSSet` and `NSDictionary` types
>   using lightweight generic parameterization are imported by Swift with
>   information about the type of their contents preserved.
>   ...
>   Aside from these Foundation collection classes, Objective-C
>   lightweight generics **are ignored by Swift.** Any other types using
>   lightweight generics are imported into Swift as if they were
>   unparameterised.

`NSMutableArray` is not in the list of Foundation types whose
lightweight generic parameterization is preserved in Swift.

*Example:* The Objective-C properties

```
@property(strong, nonatomic, nonnull) NSArray<NSString *> *anArrayProperty;
@property(strong, nonatomic, nonnull) NSMutableArray<NSString *> *aMutableArrayProperty;
```

are imported by Swift (as you can see using "Navigate -> Jump to Generated Interface" in the Xcode menu) as

```
public var anArrayProperty: [String]
public var aMutableArrayProperty: NSMutableArray
```